# Do I need to define any relationship between these two entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

Hello everyone and sorry for this noob question. I'm currently developing an ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebAPI for a Travel Planner & Assistant web application. I am using EF Core and Identity.

My model consists of the following classes:

`Vacation`, `Reservation`, `Hotel`, `Room`, `Review`, a custom `IdentityUser` and `Record`,`UserRecord` for a better management of the creation and modification date and user.

Each `Vacation` has a `List<Reservation>`; each `Hotel` has a `List<Room>` and a `List<Review>`.

My question is, should I define any relationship between `Reservation` and `Room`?

I'm thinking each `Reservation` should know which `Room` is going to book, so it seems logical to have the `Room` inside. But that instance of `Room` already exists in the `List<Room>` of the `Hotel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm thinking each Reservation should know which Room is going to book,
> so it seems logical to have the Room inside. But that instance of Room
> already exists in the List of the Hotel.

What you tought is totally correct. You don't need to add a collection naivgational property of type `Reservation` (e.g. `List<Reservation>`) into your `Room` entity.

By adding a `Room` navigational property on `Reservation` entity, EF Core can handle the remainging things and by applying default convention it will consider that a reservation is for one room and a room can be related to multiple reservations even you don't created the reservation type into the `Room` entity.

Comment: Thanks, very useful! So If I will add a `Room` navigation property into my `Reservation`, I also have to add a `[ForeignKey(nameof(Room))] string RoomId`, right?

Comment: Exact you can add but it is not required. The Room property is enough by convetion. If you don't add the RoomId, EF Core will create a default FK name Room_Id into your databse but you'll not be able to use it into your C#. On my side I always add a property that represent my FK in my databse. So yes, add that property RoomId.

Answer (score -1):

What I think, you should have a new entity HotelRoom, which contains Hotel and Room, many to many relation between Hotel and Room. Then for every Reservation you should have Hotel and a list of HotelRoom in it.

```
public class Hotel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Room
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }
}
public class HotelRoom
{
    public int HotelId { get; set; }
    public Hotel Hotel { get; set; }
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public Room Room { get; set; }
}

public class Reservation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int HotelId { get; set; }
    public Hotel Hotel { get; set; }
    public List<HotelRoom> HotelRooms { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I know what you're talking about, but it doesn't apply here. It's not like I am working with videos that can be contained by multiple playlists. A hotel can have multiple rooms, but a room only belongs to one hotel (One-To-Many).

Comment: You are right, if there is a single Hotel, it will work, but if there is more than one hotel, then above model will work. If you are working with a single hotel then it's ok. Best of luck.

Comment: I am working with multiple hotels, but Many-To-Many isn't the way to go here. That would mean that a room can exist in more than one hotel, which is impossible (at least in the real world).

Comment: Then you need different Room table for each Hotel. right?

Comment: No, bro... `Hotel` entity contains a collection navigation property (`List<Room>`); `Room` entity contains a `Hotel` navigation property and also a foreign key `HotelId`. That's how you define One-To-Many relationships using EF Core.